# Python-random number and its frequency

Tags: python, random, frequency

> The function `randint` from the random module can be used to produce random numbers. A call on `random.randint(1, 6)`, for example, will produce the values 1 to 6 with equal probability. Write a program that loops 1000 times. On each iteration it makes two calls on `randint` to simulate rolling a pair of dice. Compute the sum of the two dice, and record the number of times each value appears.
>
> The output should be two columns. One displays all the sums (i.e. from 2 to 12) and the other displays the sums' respective frequencies in 1000 times.

My code is shown below:

```
import random
freq=[0]*13

for i in range(1000):
    Sum=random.randint(1,6)+random.randint(1,6)
    #compute the sum of two random numbers
    freq[sum]+=1
    #add on the frequency of a particular sum

for Sum in xrange(2,13):
    print Sum, freq[Sum]
    #Print a column of sums and a column of their frequencies
```

However, I didn't manage to get any results.

Comment: Would it be possible to tell us what happens instead?

Comment: @PedrodelSol Maybe, but why not? They have made the main parts by themselves and now are asking for hints.

Comment: you mean your code snippet contains unexpected indent and should edit `freq[sum]+=1` to `freq[Sum]+=1` ?

Comment: BTW, [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) exists and contains a guide for e.g. the case of identifiers.

Comment: ...and `sum` (not `Sum`) is a Python built-in function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use `Sum` because simple variables should not be capitalized.

You shouldn't use `sum` because that would shadow the built-in `sum()`.

Use a different non-capitalized variable name.  I suggest `diceSum`; that's also stating a bit about the context, the idea behind your program etc. so a reader understands it faster.

You don't want to make any readers of your code happy?  Think again.  You asked for help here ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import random
freq=[0]*13

for i in range(1000):
  Sum=random.randint(1,6)+random.randint(1,6)
   #compute the sum of two random numbers
  freq[Sum]+=1
  #add on the frequency of a particular sum

for Sum in xrange(2,13):
  print Sum, freq[Sum]
  #Print a column of sums and a column of their frequencies
```

There's a grammar case error on **sum**

The seed generator that python uses should suffice to your task.

Comment: It is exactly the same code, with a different indenting and a `#!` shebang added - which, at least on my PC, wouldn't work, because my Python isn't installed under `/usr/local/`. Better suggest `#!/usr/bin/env python` or `#!/usr/bin/env python2.7`.

Comment: I agree, removing it.

Comment: Oh, ok. I didn't see the `sum` spelling.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a typo error. `Sum` variable is wrongly typed as `sum`.

Below is the modified code in python 3.x

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import random

freq= [0]*13

for i in range(1000):
    #compute the sum of two random numbers
    Sum = random.randint(1,6)+random.randint(1,6)

    #add on the frequency of a particular sum
    freq[Sum] += 1

for Sum in range(2,13):
    #Print a column of sums and a column of their frequencies
    print(Sum, freq[Sum])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
frequency_dict={}
for i in range(100):
    number=random.randint(1,10)
    if number in frequency_dict:
        frequency_dict[number] +=1
    else:
        frequency_dict[number] =1
    for key in frequency_dict:
        print(f'{"Number":<10}',f'{"Frequency":<10}')
        print(f'{key:<10}',f'{frequency_dict[key]:<10}')
```